# Why does the sum of my data change in a merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, `sales` and `plan` as follows:

```
                                  units
  retailer  product  date 

  1         1        2018-12-30   355
  1         1        2017-12-31   312
  1         1        2018-01-01   370
  ...


                                  plan_units
  retailer  product  date
  1         1        2018-01-01   360
  1         1        2018-01-02   380
  1         1        2018-01-03   330
  ...
```

`[retailer, product, date]` is the index.

Before merging, `sales['units'].sum()` is 123,456. However:

```
pd.merge(sales, plan, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')['units'].sum()
```

is **257,379**, i.e. more than I had before.

The indices of the two dataframes are not the same, hence `how='outer'`. However how am I ending up with more in the merged result?

Comment: Guess it contains duplicate index , in sales and plan , can you try ,pd.concat([sales,plan],1)['units'].sum(), and show the result

Comment: Thanks @Wen it did, can you add as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem should be sales and plan contains duplicated index , which making the merge create multiple line for each match row

For example even using concat , you will have the same problem ,since the default is `outer`.

```
pd.concat([sales,plan],1)['units'].sum()
```

Example :

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,1,2],'val':[1,1,1]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,1,2],'val':[1,1,1]})
df1.merge(df2,on='key')
Out[291]: 
   key  val_x  val_y
0    1      1      1
1    1      1      1
2    1      1      1
3    1      1      1
4    2      1      1
```